# How to predict after training?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

my csv data is here: https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/abalone_train.csv
I want to predict "Age" According to other columns. The training code is here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Make numpy values easier to read.
np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
abalone_train = pd.read_csv("https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/abalone_train.csv", header=None, 
names=["Length", "Diameter", "Height", "Whole weight", "Shucked weight","Viscera weight", "Shell weight", "Age"])
abalone_train.head()
abalone_features = abalone_train.copy()
abalone_labels = abalone_features.pop('Age')
abalone_features = np.array(abalone_features)
abalone_features
abalone_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
layers.Dense(64),
layers.Dense(1)
])

abalone_model.compile(loss = tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam())
abalone_model.fit(abalone_features, abalone_labels, epochs=10)
```

Output:

> Epoch 1/10 104/104 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step -
> loss: 63.1474 Epoch 2/10 104/104 [==============================] - 0s
> 924us/step - loss: 11.8933 Epoch 3/10 104/104
> [==============================] - 0s 920us/step - loss: 8.4037 Epoch
> 4/10 104/104 [==============================] - 0s 885us/step - loss:
> 7.9656 Epoch 5/10 104/104 [==============================] - 0s 900us/step - loss: 7.5481 Epoch 6/10 104/104
> [==============================] - 0s 908us/step - loss: 7.2339 Epoch
> 7/10 104/104 [==============================] - 0s 926us/step - loss:
> 6.9871 Epoch 8/10 104/104 [==============================] - 0s 919us/step - loss: 6.7886 Epoch 9/10 104/104
> [==============================] - 0s 956us/step - loss: 6.6482 Epoch
> 10/10 104/104 [==============================] - 0s 953us/step - loss:
> 6.5404 <tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f20abb1a518>

Now I want to upload another csv file which has blank "Age" column and see the prediction but I'm stuck. I got some lessons but in all lessons until the "epoch" stage. After the "epoch" stage, how can I import my "blank Age" csv file and see the "Age predictions"?

Comment: `model.predict(new_data)`?

Comment: #yes, it worked I added this code too:
score = norm_abalone_model.predict(abalone_predict, verbose=0)
# Save prediction as csv
np.savetxt("score.csv", score, delimiter=",")
#check if score.csv exit in google colab
!ls
#Download the predicted data as a csv
files.download('score.csv')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#predict), a `Sequential` object has a `predict` method.
Input data can be:

- NumPy array
- A TensorFlow tensor or a list of tensor
- a `tf.data` dataset

You can use `abalone_model.predict(YourData)`, where `YourData` is one of the mentioned data type. Of course, you can use `predict()` on your own training data which will likely to overfit. Try on a disjoined validation or test set if provided or split the dataset available.
Here you can find a nice example for regression problems like the one you are facing: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression